# Paint.NET equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, processing, paint.net, image-editing

On Windows, my favorite image editor is Paint.NET. However, on Linux, GIMP is as unfriendly as photoshop despite having less features. (i.e. It takes ages to load, their's far too much stuff).

Most of my image editing is simple things where Photoshop or GIMP would be overkill. Paint.NET does not run on Wine or Mono.

So is there any similar fast and simple but powerful image editor available for Linux?

EDIT: There is a Mono version available, but I don't want to have to deal with installing svn versions of mono, and compiling the version myself.

Comment: Could we as OS X to this thread?

Comment: @Mike . No. While a lot of Linux apps produce Mac versions, the opposite is not true.

Comment: @Mike, see yesterday's "What is the best Paint-like program for Mac OS X?" at http://superuser.com/questions/13354/what-is-the-best-paint-like-program-for-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/) looks pretty good.

> Pinta is a drawing/editing program modeled after Paint.NET. It's goal is to provide a simplified alternative to GIMP for casual users. It is currently early in development.

[image]

Comment: I had never heard of this before. I found that it is a very clean, light weight (faster loading) alternative to Gimp. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

KDE comes with [KolourPaint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KolourPaint), which is essentially exactly like Paint for windows. If you want a little more power, KOffice includes [Krita](http://www.koffice.org/krita), which I've really liked. I'm sure there are also some GTK-based apps if that's your preference but I've definitely found both KolorPaint and Krita useful, so you really should check them out.

Comment: Paint.NET is quite a bit more advanced than standard windows paint

Comment: Krita is quite a bit more advanced than Paint.NET

Comment: I've tried this out, and it seems to be good.

Comment: It's actually called **KolourPaint** (note the British-influenced spelling), and at least on (K)Ubuntu it comes in a package called kolourpaint: http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/kolourpaint. Can you fix that in the post? Other than that, +1.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like paint.net can run on Mono the .NET implemetation for linux. The linux version is called [paint-mono](http://code.google.com/p/paint-mono/). Not sure you can find readily available binaries for that, but maybe you don't mind compiling it from the source code ;)

Comment: I'd like to stay away from compiling beta software (the port is beta. Even the screenshot on the homepage shows some issues)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check out [inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/).  It is a multi-platform vector image editor.  Vector editing is a little different than pixel-based editing, but I find that it to be preferable -- you can move items around, change colours, fill styles, etc, and, when your done, export it to an image.

See also the [Bitmap Editor? thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=499816) on the ubuntu forums.

Comment: Vector editing is great, but that's not what he's asking about - he wants to edit images. Inkscape is more analogous to Adobe Illustrator, while Paint.net is more like Photoshop.